# ERROR 310: too many redirects. Occurring with php coded pages for website I am coding

Tags: php, redirect, web

I am currently coding pages for a social network (it's only going to run locally) for my senior project and I am running in to these redirect errors that I have no clue on how to solve. There are around three pages that have the 'header('location:...') code in it. I didn't know what it would do at the different levels of coding so I put all of the coding with an equal amount of indention.

index.php

```
<? include("inc/incfiles/header.inc.php"); ?>
<?
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
//declaring variables to prevent errors
$fn = ""; //First Name
$ln = ""; //Last Name
$un = ""; //Username
$em = ""; //Email
$em2 = ""; //Email 2
$pswd = ""; //Password
$pswd2 = ""; //Password 2
$d = ""; //Sign up Date
$u_check = ""; //Check if username exists
//registration form
$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
$d = date("y-m-d"); // Year - Month - Day

if ($reg) {
if ($em==$em2) {
// Check if user already exists
$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
// Count the amount of rows where username = $un
$check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
if ($check == 0) {
//check all of the fields have been filled in
if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {
// check that passwords match
if ($pswd==$pswd2) {
// check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters
if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";
}
else
{
// check the length of the password is between 5 and 30 characters long
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}
else
{
//encrypt password and password 2 using md5 before sending to database
$pswd = md5($pswd);
$pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','d','0')");
die("<h2>Welcome to Rebel Connect</h2>Login to your account to get started.");
}
}
}
else {
echo "Your passwords don't match!";
}
}
else 
{
echo "Please fill in all fields";
}
}
else
{
echo "Username already taken.";
}
}
else {
echo "Your e-mails don't match!";
}
}
?>
<?
//Login Script
if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["user_password"])) {
    $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$password_login' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    //Check for their existance
    $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
    if ($userCount == 1) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id = $row["id"];
    }
         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
         $_Session["password_login"] = $password_login;
         header("location: index.php");
         exit();
         } else {
         echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
         exit();
    }
}
?>
<table class="homepageTable">
        <tr>
            <td width="60%" valign="top">
             <h2>Already a member? Login below.</h2>
             <form>
                <input type="text" size="25" name="user_login" id="user_login" placeholder="username" />
                <input type="password" size="25" name="user_password" id="user_password" placeholder="password" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Login to your account!">
             </form>
            </td>
            <td width="40%" valign="top">
             <h2>Sign up below...</h2>
            <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<? echo $fn; ?>">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<? echo $ln; ?>">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<? echo $un; ?>">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<? echo $em; ?>">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="email2" placeholder="Re-enter Email" value="<? echo $em2; ?>">
            <input type="password" size="25" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="<? echo $pswd; ?>">
            <input type="password" size="25" name="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password" value="<? echo $pswd2; ?>"><br />
            <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!">
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

header.inc.php

```
<?
include ("inc/scripts/mysql_connect.inc.php");
// starts the session
session_start();
// checks whether the user is logged in or not
$user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
else
{
header("location: home.php");
exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Rebel Reach - PHS Student Social Network</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerMenu">
      <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                  <img src="img/find_friends_logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="search_box">
                  <form method="get" action="search.php" id="search">
                  <input name="q" type="text" size="60" placeholder="Search..." />
                  </form>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                  <a href="#">Home</a>
                  <a href="#">About</a>
                  <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                  <a href="#">Login</a>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

home.php

```
<?
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
//If the user is not logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
    header('location: index.php');
    exit();
}
else
{
//If the user is logged in
echo "Hi, $user, You're logged in<br />Welcome to what is soon to be your NEWSFEED";
}
?>
```

Comment: Holy unreadable code, batman... SO's editor will accept indenting in pasted code. you just have to hit the `{}` button on highlighted text to get it into a code-formatted block (and all that does it put 4 spaces at the start of each line).

Comment: Too many redirects can be significant of an infinite loop of redirects (this is actually the only reason I've seen this error occur). Make sure you don't have conditions where you redirect from one page to another, only to be redirected back to the original page.

Comment: @Jasper I just looked back at some of the coding in particular, the redirects (wish i could make a redirect tree but that's too much trouble.

Index.php
    ^
redirects to index.php

header.inc.php
^             ^
index.php     home.php
                 ^
              index.php

basically what it does is when it reads header.inc.php code for header redirects, if yes, goto index.php, if not goto home.php and it has the same code as header.inc.php header wise. and home.php will do the same thing header.inc.php does except instead of redirecting to home.php like header.inc.php it goto index.php

Answer (score 3):

You've got a catch-22 in your code:

index.php includes your function library
the function library checks for the existence of that session variable.
if the variable doesn't exist, redirect to index.php

e.g. you've written a very complicated version of the classic BASIC `10 GOTO 10`.

Comment: so basically what is happening is a loop. It reads the 10 as a variable, and then is redirected back to the beginning of this variable? and keeps doing that?

Comment: put in some code to except `index.php` from the session variable exemption.

Comment: naw, that's old BASIC code, the stuff they used to teach kids on Apple ][ computers and whatnot. "line 10: goto line 10". basically you'd have something like `if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != 'index.php') && (... session var check here ...)`

Comment: yay xD haha time to do more searching. from what jasper said, it would kind of make sense that it is a loop because home.php contains the same header(location: url) code as header.inc.php.